# I installed GraphViz to run the 'seqtreedisplay' function in R (TraMineR), but I keep running into error messages

Tags: r, graphviz, traminer

I am trying to run the 'seqtreedisplay()' function using TraMineR, but I keep running into the error message below:

```
> seqtreedisplay(wardTree, type = "d", border = NA, show.depth = TRUE)
```

[>] GraphViz version  found.
지정된 경로를 찾을 수 없습니다.
Error in disstreedisplayInternal(tree = tree, filename = filename, tmpdisstree = tmpdisstree,  :
[!] GraphViz was not found. If you haven't, please install GraphViz to use this function: see http://www.graphviz.org
[!] If GraphViz is installed on your computer, you need to specify the GraphViz installation directory using the argument gvpath='installdir'
[!] You can also add this directory to the PATH environment variable
[!] GraphViz installation directory usually looks like 'C:\Program Files\GraphViz'

I installed the **graphviz-5.0.1 (64-bit) EXE installer** in **C:\Program Files\Graphviz**. I also checked whether it was properly installed (*click to see image →*)
[by running the 'dot -V' command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QXou.png).
Paths were also added to the environment variable (both user and system).

I went through these processes several times, restarted the computer after adding the path to the system, and reinstalled various versions of GraphViz.
Plus, I also tried to (*click to see image →*) [add the directory to GraphViz in R and tried the gvpath as well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnySK.png). However, the same error message comes up.

I think the installation of GraphViz has been successful, but R (I use RStudio) is just not able to find the path to GraphViz. Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I once had similar problems. In my case, the solution was to put the GraphViz directory directly into the `seqtreedisplay`call. Maybe this also works for you.

```
# specify GraphViz directory
graphviz.dir <- "C:/Program Files/GraphViz"

# call seqtreedisplay and provide GraphViz directoy
seqtreedisplay(...,
               gvpath = graphviz.dir)
```

Comment: Your solution worked! Thanks a lot! (adding the GraphViz directory directly into the seqtreedisplay seems to have been the key)